# Query PostgresSQL(9.6.5) JSONb Column with Rails 5.1.6 For multiple key value pairs

Tags: postgresql-9.6, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a column in my database called events.

```
t.jsonb "events"
```

There I store an array have hashes.

```
[{ type: 'bounce', bounce_class: '25'}...]
```

I can find the records that have a hash with the key: value pairs of type: 'bounce' and bounce_class: '25' by using this **where** statement.

```
where("events @> ?", [{type: "bounce", bounce_class: '25'}].to_json)
```

What I can't figure out is how to look for multiple values in the bounce class key: value pair without chaining a bunch of **or** statements like this.

```
where("events @> ?", [{type: "bounce", bounce_class: '25'}].to_json).or(where("events @> ?", [{type: "bounce", bounce_class: '26'}].to_json))
```

I would like to find all the records that have a type: 'bounce' and have a bounce_class of '25' or '26, or '50'.

Is there a better way than chaining **or** statements?

Thanks